# JAXB together with Builder Pattern. Is that possible?

Tags: java, jaxb, design-patterns, builder

I was wondering if anybody knows how I can use JAXB together with the Builder Pattern?
The builder pattern wants you to set the constructor as private, and JAXB says

```
"1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions myClass does not have a no-arg default constructor"
```

Is there somehow I can tell JAXB that I don't want no-arg default constructor, and that it can create a new instance using the Builder pattern somehow?

**Update**
I should note (even though it shouldn't be relevant) that I am using Axis 2 to generate my stub files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of how to do it, as I've never had to do it, but you can tell JAXB to use a factory class to generate objects. I did a quick google search on it and there appears to be some of the data you're looking for right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

jaxb provides an ObjectFactory when you generate the classes from the schema with xjc.bat

Comment: I am using Linux and I am generating the stubs with Axis 2